# Spring: Choose bean implementation depending on parent implementation

Tags: java, spring

I have one abstract class and two implementations. Let's call them `ParentAbstract`, `ParentA` and `ParentB`. `ParentAbstract` has a property of type `BeanAbstract: bean`. There are two implementations of this abstract class: `BeanA` and `BeanB`.

Is is possible to use Spring so that it will inject `BeanA` in `ParentA` and `BeanB` in `ParentB`?

Note that I cannot use `ParentA` and `ParentB` as Spring beans because they are Wicket pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ParentAbstract` add an abstract method

```
abstract setBean(BeanAbstract bean);
```

Then in the subclasses, overrride them and annotate:

```
@Override
@Autowired
@Qualifier("name") // or @Resource("name")
setBean(BeanAbstract bean) {
    this.bean=bean;
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, covariance is only allowed for return type.

Comment: Ok thanks, that answers my question. Now I have to ask a Wicket question :D

Comment: @artbristol, just a note,  `@Qualifier` is discouraged in favour of `@Resource`.

Answer (score 1):

Spring default tries to autowired by type. When there are ambiguities (such as the case is here) *you* must provide a qualifier. 
The recommended approach is either to **explicitly** declare dependencies in your configuration (`XML` or `@Configuration`) or autowire by name

```
@Resource(name="beanA")
```

Comment: The issue is that when I create a `ParentA`, I want the `bean` to be of type `BeanA`, and when I create a `ParentB`, the `bean`'s type should be `BeanB`. I use both implementations in my application.